# Overlay text in a background image not getting correct output

Tags: ffmpeg

When overlaying a text or image(test.jpg) to a background image(bg.png),output video background color is getting darker.
here input image has an alpha value .

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -i test.jpg -y -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25,-pix_fmt yuv420p" -shortest -t 10 tesy.mp4
```

Output excepted : https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5C3x.png

Output I got  is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/reujS.png

If you see background color has huge differnce in the output I got

Below is the background image(bg.png) to which i am overlaying some image(test.jpg)
[image]

Use this image and overlay a test image, and let me know the difference in background color .

Answer (score 0):

Add the [premultiply filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#premultiply) for these particular PNG files:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i bg.png -i test.jpg -filter_complex "[0]premultiply=inplace=1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=25:25:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

Or create the PNG with no alpha.

Or use the [color filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) to make the background:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=purple:s=1280x720 -i test.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=25:25:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. can you recheck the updated question